# CXJS how to confirm to leave an routed link url?

Tags: cxjs

Take the standard dashboard starter app: https://cxjs.io/quickstart . Click in the left menu from "page" to "page".

How can i prevent unloading a content component with an onblur confirm?

in the controller ondestroy seems not to work.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently supported, but it would be a great feature.

https://github.com/codaxy/cxjs/issues/408